# Regex: match only last 2 digits and ignore whitespaces at the end of line

Tags: regex

**Example:**

> 32-12•
> 32-12•••
> 32-12-52••
> 32-12-53-12

(let's say Bullet Point "•" is Whitespaces)

What I have tried is

`/(?<=^.*)\d{2}(?= *)$/gm`

but it seem like it does match only last 2 digits that whitespaces doesn't concat like this

> 32-12•
> 32-12•••
> 32-12-52••
> 32-12-53-**12**

(let's say **bold** strings are where regex **matched**)

but what I want is last 2 digits ignore whitespaces like this

> 32-**12**•
> 32-**12**•••
> 32-12-**52**••
> 32-12-53-**12**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\d{2}(?= *$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tSPrYh/1). To match any whitespaces, replace the literal space with as `\s` shorthand character class: `\d{2}(?=\s*$)`.

*Details*:

- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?= *$)` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more chars and the end of string position to appear immediately to the right of the current location.